# How to get actual key pressed from keytyped java

Tags: java, keypress

I've got the following code

```
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
int i = e.getKeyChar();
 for(int j = 0; j<numbers.length; j++) {
    if(i!= numbers[j]){
 panel.setStatus("player must use 1-5");
 return;
 }}
if(!panel.isValidAssign(row, col, i)){
    panel.setStatus("invalid user move");
    return;
}
panel.makeAssign(row, col, i);
}
```

I'm trying to receive the user input as number between 1 & 5.
So far I'm only receiving the unicode for each key whereas I need the actual number.
How do I change the code to reflect this?

Comment: Unicode of number - 48 = number itself

Comment: There is a function for this: `Character.getNumericValue( codePoint );`.